# La siguiente configuración me funciona en mi servidor local pero no en mi servidor remoto

Tags: php, php5

```
        <form method="POST">
            <div id="fade-box">
                <input type="text" name="nombre_usuario" id="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" title="Introduzca su nombre de usuario" required>
                <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" title="Introduzca su contraseña" required>
                <div class="botones_con_crear">
                    <button type="submit" name="Conectarse">Conectarse</button>
                    <button id="btn-crear-cuenta">Crear Cuenta</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


    <?php
        require_once "conexion.php";

        if (isset($_POST['Conectarse'])) {
            $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre_usuario']) ? trim($_POST['nombre_usuario']) : '';
            $contraseña = isset($_POST['contraseña']) ? $_POST['contraseña'] : '';
            try {
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT usuario, password FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=SHA1(?) AND password=SHA2(?, 256)");
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nombre, $contraseña);
                $stmt->execute();
                $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
                if ($resultado->num_rows == 1) {
                    header("Location: datos");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    echo "<i>Usuario o contraseña no válidos</i>";
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<i>Error en la consulta SQL</i>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<i>Formulario no enviado</i>";
        }
    ?>
```

Esto se trata de mi TFG y en mi servidor local funciona la autenticación, pero en mi servidor remoto no. EL remoto no tiene, que yo sepa ninguna librería añadida de ningún tipo, y el local tampoco. Me estoy introduciendo al mundo de la programación y es bastante lioso :)

Comment: Puedes subir a tu servidor remoto un archivo PHP con únicamente el código de `phpinfo();` y así cuando lo ejecutes te saldrá la información de librerías y demás que tiene instalado el servidor. A partir de ahí ya podrías evaluar si tiene o no lo librerías necesarias para que tu aplicación funcione.

Comment: Revisa el log de php del servidor.

Comment: Ya he añadido en phpinfo(); y no tengo ninguna librería instalada :)
que debería de ver exactamente?? mi dominio se llama "https://miproyecto2asir.es/inicio_sesion/"